# Pass gridview selected item position to ViewFipper android

Tags: android, gridview, viewflipper

I am displaying the images from web service in `GridView` . When user selects the item in the `GridView` it opens ViewsFlipper to display the same image in Larger Resolution (obtained from web service with another link)

The problem is When user selects 3rd item in `GridView` it opens ViewFlipper with Ist item(not with 3rd item)

How to pass the position of the selected item ?

GridViewActivity.java

```
grid_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TextView txt_product_name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_name);
                String product_name=txt_product_name.getText().toString();

                TextView txt_product_path=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_fetch_name);
                String product_path=txt_product_path.getText().toString();

                TextView txt_product_id=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_id);
                String product_id=txt_product_id.getText().toString();

                TextView txt_product_details=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_details);
                String product_details=txt_product_details.getText().toString();



                Intent intent=new Intent(GetInspiredProducts.this,ViewFlipperActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("product_name", product_name);
                intent.putExtra("product_path", product_path);

                intent.putExtra("product_id", product_id);
                intent.putExtra("product_details", product_details);

                intent.putExtra("cat_id", cat_id);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

ViewFlipperActivity.java

```
protected List doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(GetInspiredProductDetail.this)==true) {


            try{
                jsonObj=userFunctions.getInspiredProducts(cat_id);
                Log.e("getInspiredCategory", "kargetinsp "+jsonObj);


                JSONArray json_array=jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");

                for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject json_obj=json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String category=json_obj.getString("post");


                    JSONObject json_obj_=new JSONObject(category);

                    String picture_path=json_obj_.getString("PicturePath");
                    String picture_name=json_obj_.getString("PictureName");
                    String picture_id=json_obj_.getString("PictureId");
                    String picture_details=json_obj_.getString("PictureDetails");


                    HashMap<String, String> hash_map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hash_map.put("flipper_image",AllLinks.PRODUCTS_LARGE_IMAGE_URI+picture_path);
                    hash_map.put("flipper_name",picture_name);
                    hash_map.put("flipper_path",picture_path);
                    category_hash_map.add(hash_map);


                    Log.e("VIEW_FLIPPER1", "karjeev "+picture_path);

                    /*HashMap<String, String> hash_map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hash_map.put("products_pic_path",  AllLinks.PRODUCTS_THUMB_PICTURE_PATH+picture_path);
                    hash_map.put("products_pic_name", picture_name);
                    category_hash_map.add(hash_map);    */

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

ViewFlipperAdapter.java

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_page_copy, null);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);



        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_det);
        final TextView txtPath = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prod_path);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get("flipper_image"),img);
        txtName.setText(song.get("flipper_name"));
        txtPath.setText(song.get("flipper_path"));

        view.setContentDescription(content);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String path=txtPath.getText().toString();

                Log.d("image path", String.valueOf(v.getContentDescription()));
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,ImageZoom.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", AllLinks.PRODUCTS_LARGE_IMAGE_URI+path);           
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: How did you Download image for view fliper? What is the parameters for that web service . I guess you are sending wrong parameter.

Comment: I used : http://www.blueprintstudios.com/images/gallery/thumbs/ -- for GridView (Thumb images)   & : http://www.blueprintstudios.com/images/cache/ -- for ViewFlipper (large images)

Comment: Your question is large image is wrong right? I am not able to open your link. That is not problem. What are the inputs needed to retrieve your large image. Did you check that thing ? For example image id or something

Comment: http://www.blueprintstudios.com/images/gallery/thumbs/01365181644.jpg &   http://www.blueprintstudios.com/images/cache/01365181644.jpg

Comment: I passed entire images to GridView and Entire images to ViewFlipper . Dont know how to passed selected images position to Viewflipper

Comment: I check your code where is the download large image download code?

Comment: In doInBackground "  getInspiredProducts(cat_id)"                          hash_map.put("flipper_image",AllLinks.PRODUCTS_LARGE_IMAGE_URI+picture_path);